# Can I specify an alternative association name when I use joins() in ActiveRecord/arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I am on the trail of an issue where ActiveRecord seemed to be generating an invalid query.

Here is the essence of the model and how the controller is using it:

```
class Licence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :owner_organisation, :class_name => 'Organisation'
  # omitting other relationships

  def self.search(params = {})
    collection = self
    table = self.arel_table

    # omitting filtering of the collection

    case params[:order]

      # these two work:
      when 'generated_by'
        collection = collection.joins(:organisation).
                                order('organisations.name ASC')
      when 'generated_by_reverse'
        collection = collection.joins(:organisation).
                                order('organisations.name DESC')

      # these two cause the problem:
      when 'owner'
        collection = collection.joins(:owner_organisation).
                                order('owner_organisations.name ASC')
      when 'owner_reverse'
        collection = collection.joins(:owner_organisation).
                                order('owner_organisations.name DESC')
                              # ^- this order() is almost certainly wrong too, but I
                              #    will fix that once I get a table name I can predict...

      # omitting other orderings
    end

    collection
  end

end

class LicencesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @licences = Licence.search(params).
      includes(:organisation, :user, :owner_organisation, :profile)
  end

end
```

You'll notice that the model *joins* owner_organisation whereas the controller *includes* it. This appears to be part of the problem.

This causes a strange query to be created, and I get an error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: owner_organisations_licences.id:
```

And indeed the query doesn't include a table with this name: (I cut down the query because there are a *lot* of columns being selected.)

```
SELECT
  "licences"."id" AS t0_r0,           # omitting rest of the columns for all these
  "organisations"."id" AS t1_r0,
  "users"."id" AS t2_r0,
  "dongles"."id" AS t3_r0,
  "owner_organisations_licences"."id" AS t4_r0,      # this is the problem
  "profiles"."id" AS t5_r0
FROM "licences"
  INNER JOIN "organisations"
    ON "organisations"."id" = "licences"."owner_organisation_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "organisations" "organisations_licences"
    ON "organisations_licences"."id" = "licences"."organisation_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "users"
    ON "users"."id" = "licences"."user_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "dongles"
    ON "dongles"."id" = "licences"."dongle_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles"
    ON "profiles"."id" = "licences"."profile_id"
WHERE "licences"."parent_licence_id" IS NULL
ORDER BY owner_organisations.name ASC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I can see that there is a naming scheme going on here where my `includes(:organisations)` becomes `organisations_licences` in the query. But `owner_organisation` was already used with `joins(:owner_organisation)`, so it has been put in as an `INNER JOIN` - and for whatever reason, `#joins` doesn't have the same convention as `#includes`, so it has the "wrong" name. But then, for whatever reason, it uses `owner_organisations_licences` when it's specifying what to select, thus the query is invalid.

I figure I can probably get around this if there is a way to tell arel what name to give the joined table, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect that `includes` always performs a `JOIN` on the database level. In fact `include` has two different strategies and it might use `JOIN` or it might fire a second query (what is still faster than the common N+1 problem `includes` tries to solve). You might be interested in this [article](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) about how `includes works`.

The answer to your problem: Do not use `joins` and `includes` on the same table at the same time. In Rails 4 there is a new method `references` that solves this problem:

```
case params[:order]
when 'generated_by'
  collection = collection.includes(:organisation).
                          order('organisations.name ASC').
                          references(:organisations)
when 'generated_by_reverse'
  collection = collection.includes(:organisation).
                          order('organisations.name DESC').
                          references(:organisations)
when 'owner'
  collection = collection.includes(:owner_organisation).
                          order('organisations.name ASC').
                          references(:organisations)
when 'owner_reverse'
  collection = collection.includes(:owner_organisation).
                          order('organisations.name DESC').
                          references(:organisations)
end
```

Comment: I guess that answers the question of what order() will be called after the actual issue is figured out (assuming that it doesn't involve correcting the name of that table/association), but it doesn't really answer the question itself.

Comment: That article has a good tip actually, in that it says I can use preload() to avoid Rails choosing to use a join. Changing that certainly stops the issue (although it may cause an unforeseen performance hit. Right now this page, complicated as it might be, executes as a single query, which is something I rather like.) references sounds nice, but I'd have to upgrade to Rails 4 first. I have been wanting to do that anyway, though, so it's under consideration.